# static value with svm.SVR.predict()

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, svm, python-3.5

I have attempted to assess the relevance some predictions based on a `dataset (n * 6)`, but I am wondering about the causes of *strange* results I am currently facing with `svr.SVR.predict`. The below code could illustrate my statement:

```
d = DataReader(...)
a = d.iloc[:,0:5]
b = d.iloc[:,5]
cut = 10
z = d.iloc[len(d.index) - cut :,0:5]

X,y = np.asarray(a[:-10]), np.asarray(b[:-10]) # train set
XT,yT = np.asarray(z), np.asarray(b[-10:]) # test set

clf = svm.SVR(kernel = 'rbf', gamma=0.1, C=1e3)
y_hat = clf.fit(X,y).predict(XT[i]) #, i = 0,1...
```

yields **amazing** *static values* for all `i`, despite differences in `XT[i]` (*Ps:* `XT[i].shape = (5,)`).

In a nutshell, the goal consisted of comparing `y_hat` `vs` `yT`.

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to normalize before SVM. Try the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

d = DataReader(...)
a = d.iloc[:,0:5]
b = d.iloc[:,5]
cut = 10
z = d.iloc[len(d.index) - cut :,0:5]

X,y = np.asarray(a[:-10]), np.asarray(b[:-10]) # train set
XT,yT = np.asarray(z), np.asarray(b[-10:]) # test set

scl = StandardScaler()
X = scl.fit_transform(X)
XT = scl.transform(XT)

clf = svm.SVR(kernel = 'rbf', gamma=0.1, C=1e3)
y_hat = clf.fit(X,y).predict(XT[i]) #, i = 0,1...
```